# MySql stored procedures, transactions and rollbacks

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, commit, rollback

I can't find an optimal way to use transactions in a MySql Stored Procedure. I want to `ROLLBACK` if anything fails:

```
BEGIN

    SET autocommit=0;
    START TRANSACTION;

    DELETE FROM customers;
    INSERT INTO customers VALUES(100);
    INSERT INTO customers VALUES('wrong type');

    COMMIT;
END
```

1) Is `autocommit=0` required?

2) If the second `INSERT` breaks (and it does of course) the first `INSERT` is not rolled back. The procedure simply continues down to the `COMMIT`. How can I prevent this?

3) I've found I can `DECLARE HANDLER`, should I use this instruction or is there a simpler way to say that if any command fails, the stored procedure should `ROLLBACK` and fail too?

`DECLARE HANDLER` works fine, but since I have MySql version 5.1 I can't use `RESIGNAL`. So if an error occurs, the caller won't be notified:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK; 
    -- RESIGNAL; not in my version :(
END;

START TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 13):

Answer to 1: You don't need to set autocommit=0

> With START TRANSACTION, autocommit remains disabled until you end the
>   transaction with COMMIT or ROLLBACK. The autocommit mode then reverts
>   to its previous state.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html

Comment: Another statement on that page `To disable autocommit mode implicitly for a single series of statements, use the START TRANSACTION statement`

Answer (score 1):

Different Approach to Answer 2: You could use a boolean variable to know if you should COMMIT or ROLLBACK. For example:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE `should_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `should_rollback` = TRUE;

START TRANSACTION;

DELETE FROM customers;
INSERT INTO customers VALUES(100);
INSERT INTO customers VALUES('wrong type');

IF `should_rollback` THEN
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
    COMMIT;
END IF;
END
```

Or, you could use your very usefull 3)